# Generating n-digit numbers sequenced by sum of individual digits (without recursion)

Tags: java, php, c++, combinatorics, permutation

I'm looking to generate all possible values of n-digit number, in the following order, where the sequence is dictated by the sum of the individual digits.

For example, with `n = 3`:

```
111     sum = 3
112     sum = 4
121
211
122     sum = 5
212
221
113
131
311
114     sum = 6
141
411
:::
999     sum = 27
```

The order within the sum group is not important.

Any help, ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Why the "no recursion" restriction? Are you concerned that using recursion would prevent the ordering behaviour you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326824/non-recursive-form-of-permuatuion-operation

Comment: Those aren't digit permutations of an n-digit number, those are length 3 combinations of 3 digits.

Comment: I think I need to rephrase this a bit. I basically need to split a number into n parts, like split a sum of 5 into 3 numbers, all >= 1 like 113 131 311 121 112 211 and so on.

Comment: Even with the edit, I don't understand the question. For one thing, in your first example 112 appears before 113, and in your second example it appears after. And how is "121" a result of splitting a "sum of 5" into "3 numbers". 1+2+1=4. Rather than saying "and so on", try to define exactly what outputs you want to see. Then perhaps you'll be able to translate that definition into code.

Comment: Why is it closed? This question is not about permutations. The question does not make sense though, in its current form. In one place that OP stays it should be a sum, but in other the OP gives an example of 3 being represented as 121??? 1+2+1 is 4, not 3.

Comment: lol "permutations of string" in the dupe-candidate does not equal "selection N digits with replacement from 1..N" does not equal "select N numbers that sum to M"

Comment: @Amit, I've edited the question to (hopefully) better reflect what you meant to ask. Apologies for the close vote, I should have looked closer at the question instead of just concentrating on the recursion bit. I've now voted to reopen and flagged to the powers that be. Hopefully you'll get enough reopen votes to bring it back on line.

Comment: I've also provided a solution in my answer which will hopefully help (still recursive but that seems an arbitrary restriction and I've explained why it shouldn't cause a problem). Unfortunately I can't un-community-wiki it so I won't be getting any more rep but that's okay, I'll survive :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can *always* turn a recursive problem into an iterative one if you maintain your own stack of important data - that's if the reason for avoiding recursion is that the language doesn't support it.

But, if the language *does* support it, then recursive solutions are far more elegant.

The only other reason I can think of for avoiding recursion is limited stack depth. In that case an iterative conversion of a recursive solution will mitigate the problem by not requiring as much stack space.

But you need to understand that the stack depth for processing n numbers only grows relative to log<sub>10</sub>n. In other words, you only get an extra stack frame per digit (only 10 stack frames to handle the full range of 32-bit integers).

*Aside:* by the time you get to that point, you're algorithm will be taking so long to run, stack frames will be the least of your problems :-)

Here's a recursive Python solution:

```
def recur (numdigits,sum,pref="",prefsum=0):
    if numdigits == 0:
        if prefsum == sum:
            print "%s, sum=%d"%(pref,prefsum)
    else:
        for i in range (1,10):
            recur (numdigits-1,sum,"%s%d"%(pref,i),prefsum+i)

def do (n):
    for i in range (1,n*9+1):
        recur (n,i)

do (2)
do (3)
```

which outputs (for 2 and 3):

```
11, sum=2          111, sum=3
12, sum=3          112, sum=4
21, sum=3          121, sum=4
13, sum=4          211, sum=4
22, sum=4          113, sum=5
31, sum=4          122, sum=5
14, sum=5          131, sum=5
23, sum=5          212, sum=5
32, sum=5          221, sum=5
41, sum=5          311, sum=5
15, sum=6          114, sum=6
 :    :             :     :
89, sum=17         989, sum=26
98, sum=17         998, sum=26
99, sum=18         999, sum=27
```

Keep in mind that solution could still be optimized somewhat - I left it in its initial form to show how elegant recursion can be. A pure-iterative solution follows, but I still prefer the recursive one.

Run the following program and use `sort` and `awk` under UNIX to get the desired order. For example:

```
go | sort | awk '{print $2}'
```

Note that this uses external tools to do the sorting but you could just as easily sort within the C code (memory permitting).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int i, sum, carry, size;
    int *pDigit;

    // Choose your desired size.

    size = 2;

    // Allocate and initialise digits.

    if ((pDigit = malloc (size * sizeof (int))) == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "No memory\n");
        return 1;
    )

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        pDigit[i] = 1;

    // Loop until overflow.

    carry = 0;
    while (carry != 1) {
        // Work out sum, then output it with number.
        // Line is sssssssssssssssssss ddddd
        //   where sss...sss is the fixed-width sum, zero padded on left (for sort)
        //   and ddd...ddd is the actual number.

        sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            sum += pDigit[i];

        printf ("%020d ", sum);
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            printf ("%d", pDigit[i]);
        printf ("\n");

        // Advance to next number.

        carry = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            pDigit[size-i-1] = pDigit[size-i-1] + carry;
            if (pDigit[size-i-1] == 10)
                pDigit[size-i-1] = 1;
            else
                carry = 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think I need to rephrase this a bit. I basically need to split a number into n parts, like split a sum of 5 into 3 numbers, all >= 1 like 113 131 311 121 112 211 and so on.

Comment: -1: Using a manually implemented stack doesn not turn recursive algorithm into an iterative one. Manual stack vs. language stack is nothing more than an implementatonal detail. When the stateent of the problem specificaly asks for an iterative algoritm, recursion with a manually implemented stack is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: @Andrey: there's no way to tell why the OP wants a non-recursive algorithm. It may be that he wants a different implementation of the algorithm, or he wants to work around Java/C++'s lack of tail-call optimization. If the latter, then its perfectly valid to re-write the recursive algorithm with a loop and heap-allocated stack.

Comment: The point is that the above results in a non-recursive *implementation* of a *recursive* algorithm. If the OP wahts a non-recursive *algorithm* specifically (as opposed to *implementetion*), the above answer (as well as your comment) misses the point completely. Please, stop making that popular naive error of mistaking a particular implementation of an algorithm for the algorithm itself. These are not even remotely the same.

Comment: "If the OP wants a non-recursive algorithm specifically". That's a big "if", especially now that the questioner has accepted this answer. I don't think it's necessarily a naive error to assume that when a questioner says he wants to avoid "recursion" he means recursive calls. If the real requirement was a non-recursive algorithm, shouldn't he have specified constant extra working space, or something?

Comment: @AndreyT, there was no reason given for the non-recursive and I can only think of two (no recursion in the language or fear of too many stack frames). The first can be worked around, the second shouldn't be a problem since stack growth is relative to logN, not N. The only purely iterative solution I could envisage was a hideous nested for-loop morass.

Answer (score 4):

Can you use [std::next_permutation](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/algorithm/next_permutation)?

> The next_permutation() function
>   attempts to transform the given range
>   of elements [start,end) into the next
>   lexicographically greater permutation
>   of elements. If it succeeds, it
>   returns true, otherwise, it returns
>   false.
>
> If a strict weak ordering function
>   object cmp is provided, it is used in
>   lieu of the < operator when comparing
>   elements.

See this: [previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326824/non-recursive-form-of-permuatuion-operation/1327043#1327043)

Comment: That's not my answer. This is - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326824/how-can-i-find-all-permutations-of-a-string-without-using-recursion/1327147#1327147.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was confusing.  I just meant thanks for pointing me to that thread.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't matter what pattern you use so long as there is a pattern (it's not entirely clear from your post whether you have a specific pattern in mind) then for n=3, start with `111` and increment until you reach `999`.

By the way, the term for what you're asking for isn't exactly "permutations".

Comment: I think I need to rephrase this a bit.
I basically need to split a number into n parts, like split a sum of 5 into 3 numbers, all >= 1
like
113
131
311
121
112
211
and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reduce your problem to two buckets:

Two bucket splits are simple:  Start with all minus one in bucket A and one in bucket B, then put one from A into B until A contains only one.

Three bucket splits are then just:  Start with all minus two in bucket A and one each in B and C.  Reduce A by one and collect all two bucket splits of three in B and C, repeat until A contains only one.