# Generate permutations iteratively without recursion or stack with Ruby/Erlang

Tags: ruby, recursion, erlang, stack, permutation

I would like to generate all permutations of a list, but I would like to filter out some of the permutations before they are added to the stack or stored anywhere.

I will filter out the permutations based on some custom ad-hoc rules.

In other words, I would like to generate a list of permutations of a large list (50-300 elements), but I would like to throw out most of the generated permutations right during the process (I know that the full number of permutations is `N!`).

I have tried Ruby with its `Array.permutation.to_a`, but it looks like it maintains a full stack during execution, so I ran out of memory (8 GB) fairly quickly.

I have also tried [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations#Erlang) Erlang solution, but it seems to perform similar to the previous Ruby one.

Are there any custom solutions to this problem?

P.S. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187815/permutations-without-recursion) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326824/how-can-i-find-all-permutations-of-a-string-without-using-recursion), but unfortunately I do not know C/C++.

Comment: You can use an algorithm called the "Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm" to generate permutations by iteration: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm

Comment: The second question you linked got a good solution, it should be easy to rewrite that to ruby.

Comment: It sounds like what you want might be less along the lines of permutation generation, and more along the lines of **list comprehensions**.

Comment: TreyE, could you please elaborate more on using list comprehensions?

Comment: Why the worry about recursion and stack? In Erlang recursion is the natural order of things.

Comment: with Erlang's natural concurrency, you could split the job into portions, increasing generation throughput. Erlang, if understood well, should be the best way to generate permutations. I have seen `Joe Armstrong` erlang example programs (http://www3.erlang.org/examples/examples-2.0.pdf) in which he writes a numerical diversion as part of a crypto system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby's `Array.permutation.to_a` does indeed produce an array. Don't use `to_a` then! It means 'to array'. `Array.permutation` gives you an 'enumerator', a generator.  Since you want to throw out most permutations, use `reject` on it.

```
res = [1,2,3,4].permutation(3).reject do |perm|
  perm.first.even? #if this line is true, the perm will be rejected
end
```

will generate all permutations of three elements and reject those with an even number on the first position. But ehm... have you seen how much 300! is?

Comment: Thanks, steenslag! I have seen how much 300! is :)

Comment: In answer to the earlier question about list comprehensions, the above is very similar.  List comprehensions can in many ways be described as a generator combined with a filter.  What steenslag has defined above is very similar to one.  Also +1 for an excellent answer I wasn't aware of - thanks for helping me learn something new about ruby steenslag!