# Generate custom permutations with Erlang

Tags: recursion, erlang, stack, permutation

*Note: This is a 'sequel' question to my previous permutations [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480487/generate-permutations-iteratively-without-recursion-or-stack-with-ruby-erlang).*

I would like to generate all permutations of a list in Erlang, but I would like to filter out some of the permutations before they are added to the stack or stored anywhere.

I will filter out the permutations based on some custom ad-hoc rules (let's call them "Filter").

In other words, I would like to generate a list of permutations of a large list (50-300 elements), but I would like to throw out most of the generated permutations right during the process (I know that the full number of permutations is N!).

[steenslag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290394/steenslag) has given me a nice [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480487/generate-permutations-iteratively-without-recursion-or-stack-with-ruby-erlang) in Ruby:

```
res = [1,2,3,4].permutation(3).reject do |perm|
  perm.first.even? #Filter: if this line is true, the perm will be rejected
end
```

How can I write something similar in Erlang?

(I have my Filter functions already written in Erlang, so I would like to do some code reuse).

By the way, can the desired Erlang solution be 'intrinsically parallel'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a possible implementation for the problem:

```
-module(perm).

-export([pred_perms/2, pred/1]).

pred(L = [H | _T]) when H > 1 ->
    L;
pred(_L) ->
    [].

do_pred_perms([], _Pred) -> 
    [[]];
do_pred_perms(L, Pred)  -> 
    [Pred([H|T]) || H <- L, T <- do_pred_perms(L--[H], Pred)].

pred_perms(List, Pred) ->
    Res = do_pred_perms(List, Pred),
    lists:filter(fun(E) -> E =/= [] end, Res).
```

It uses empty lists as placeholders for lists that must be discarded. If this is not acceptable, you can change the implementation to not use list compreension.

The pred/1 function is just an example function to use as predicate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note: this implementation is not 'intrinsically parallel'.

Comment: Dear Isac, thanks for your answer. I do L = lists:seq(1,10)., then I do F = fun perm:pred/2., and then I do perm:pred_perms(L,F). The result is ** exception error: perm:pred/2 called with one argument
     in function  perm:'-do_pred_perms/2-lc$^1/1-1-'/5
     in call from perm:'-do_pred_perms/2-lc$^0/1-0-'/3
     in call from perm:pred_perms/2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The pred function receives just 1 parameter. Change your code to: F = fun perm:pred/1. and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter permutations as soon as they constructed.

Just an example, this run() returns all permutations of [1,2,3,4] that starts with even number. The function 'check' (that filters result) 1) check if it's complete permutation (length of result == length of source list), and then 2) check condition of filtering (in my case - first digit is even).

```
run() ->
    perm([1,2,3,4],4).

perm([],_) ->
    [[]];
perm(L,N) -> [[H|T] || H <- L, T <- perm(L--[H],N), check( [H|T] ,N) ].

check(L,N) when length(L) < N -> true;
check([H|_],_) -> trunc(H/2) == H/2. .
```